# Encrypting passwords with base64

Tags: python, base64

Can I encrypt passwords in base64? I want to do this because its as easy as

```py
import os
os.popen(f"echo {userinput} | base64").read()
```

I was wondering if it is safe because its not hard to decrypt base64.

Comment: safe for what kind of use?

Comment: storing passwords

Comment: No it's not safe, and that's exactly why. It's not actually encryption, and you shouldn't encrypt passwords anyway; _hash_ them.

Comment: Encoding is not the same as encryption.

Comment: so you're asking, if it's safe in case where someone gains access to your file? no. That's why (if you don't need the password to be reconstructable) you store a hash. If you however still need the password (to decrypt them), you could use RSA for example with REALLY BIG primes.

Comment: *wondering if it is safe because its not hard to decrypt* - you're already answering it with the question. Should I put all my money under my pillow? I wonder it is safe, because it's easy to find?

Answer (score 2):

Base 64 is NOT a valid encryption method for passwords if you want it to be secure. It is barely better than plaintext.

Usually, the password is hashed and salted, and then checking passwords involves hashing the new string with the same method and checking against the stored hash.

Answer (score 0):

You just answered yourself ;] If it is "not hard to decrypt base64", you wouldn't like to use it for any secure way of storing passwords, right?

[Here](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded) are more details regarding the problems with base64.

I think that a valid option for you would be to use some higher level popular library. It's a hard topic, and it's easy to mess it up, so it's better to use some trusted and battle-tested solutions. You can take a look [here](https://theautomatic.net/2020/04/28/how-to-hide-a-password-in-a-python-script/) for some overview of available libraries.